# Understanding Lagrangian for LP

Tags: convex-optimization

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/):
[image]

While it is rue that a linear function is bounded below only when it is ZERO, in the highlighted part didn't we ignored the constrained that $x \succ 0$? Why?

If x is all positive than minimum value of g could be when $c + A^T\nu - \lambda \neq 0$. Specifically when $c + A^T\nu - \lambda \succ 0$

Answer (score 0):

The point of introducing the Lagrange function $L$ is to drop the constraints on $x$. The primal problem is actually equivalent to the unconstrained minimization of the function
$f(x) = \sup_{\lambda\ge 0,\nu} L(x,\lambda,\nu)$, because the supremum inside $f$ becomes infinite if the original constraints on $x$ are violated (including the non-negativity constraint $x \ge 0$).

That is you have the unconstrained optimization problem $\inf_x f(x)$, which is related to the dual problem through the [max-min inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max%E2%80%93min_inequality):
$$
\sup_{\lambda\ge 0,\nu} g(\lambda,\nu)
=
\sup_{\lambda\ge 0,\nu}\inf_x L(x,\lambda,\nu) \le \inf_x\sup_{\lambda\ge 0,\nu} L(x,\lambda,\nu) = \inf_x f(x)
.
$$
This is the [weak-duality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_duality), and the dual form (its left-hand side) is being simplified in your text.

So then notice that the infimum over $x$ in the dual function $g$ is also unconstrained (the original non-negativity constraints on $x$ has been dropped), and so if $c + A^T\nu - \lambda \neq 0$, then its value becomes negative infinity.